# "To become" or "to becoming"?

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

"It will take 7 years for you to become a good doctor" is correct but I would like to know if this would be also correct " It will take 7 years to becoming a good doctor" .

I don't think so because "to" is not a preposition we can't say  "it will take 7 years to a good doctor"it doesn't mean anything  so using a gerund seems not correct to me in that case.

Am I right?

Comment: You are right. **Take [time, effort etc.] to** requires the infinitive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [took him two months building/to build a house](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/304142/took-him-two-months-building-to-build-a-house)